# Yii framework controller wrapper

Tags: php, rest, yii

I am trying to set up a restful api using yii. Trying to add a wrapper that takes the results from the code being ran in the controller and returning it in json format. I am also trying to have it catch any errors[try-catch] and returning them in json format.

Right now all I can think of doing is something similar to the code below...I'd like the ability to not have to add a try/catch everytime.

```
class UserController extends Controller{

    public function actionIndex($user_id = null){
        $response = new API_Response();

        try{
            $response->success = true;
            $response->data = array("data"=>"data goes here...");
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $response->success = false;
            $response->message = $e->getMessage();
        }

        $response->send();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With more research, found I could override the api handler per each controller so now I don't have to write a whole bunch of try-catches.

```
function init(){
    $this->api_resp = new API_Response();
    Yii::app()->attachEventHandler('onException',array($this, 'handleApiError'));
}
public function handleApiError(CEvent $e){
    if($e instanceof CExceptionEvent){
        $this->api_resp->error = $e->exception->getMessage();
        $this->api_resp->send();
    }else{
        $this->api_resp->error = Yii::t('app', 'error.unknown');
        $this->api_resp->send();
    }
}
```